# Programatically duplicated product not displayed on frontend in magento (ver 1.9.0.1)

Tags: magento

I use the following script (inside a controller - action for now) for duplicating a product programatically.

```
public function indexAction()
{       
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $_product = $product->loadByAttribute('sku',$data['prod_sku']);

    $clone = $_product->duplicate();
    $clone->setSku($data['new_sku']);
    $clone->setUrlKey('foo-bar-1');

    $qty = 99;
    $is_in_stock = 1;
    $stockArray = array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                    'manage_stock' => 1,
                    'qty' => $qty,
                    'is_in_stock' => $is_in_stock,
                );

    $storeid=0; // your store id 0 is for default store id
    Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($clone->getId(), $storeid, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

    $clone->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));
    try{
        $clone->getResource()->save($clone);
         $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($clone->getId());
        foreach($stockArray as $key => $val){
            $stockItem->setData($key, $val);
        }

        $stockItem->save();
    } catch(Exception $e){
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }

    echo "new product ID is ".$clone->getId();
}
```

This works well and the product gets duplicated with supplied SKU and overwritten prices from a form.

- I can see the product in product grid in admin panel.
- Visibility is set to Catalog, Search
- Product is in stock
- Enabled and tagged to correct category and website.

Comment: Have you tried reindexing

Comment: Yes, I tried with indexing but no result.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you can not see product on frontend, because it is not available in needed website. Provided code can be executed correctly only in admin area (in frontend controller "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1180" will be generated), so code: `Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()` returned `0`, that can not be correct website for frontend.

You should replace line:

`$clone->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));`

with

`$clone->setWebsiteIds($_product->getWebsiteIds());`